Why does lsattr show different attributes for the same file?
Files in a (Ubuntu 22.04.4) Samba share mounted with cifs from /etc/fstab are returning apparently random attributes each time I run lsattr - is that normal?
/etc/fstab:
//192.168.0.7/files /mnt/nas/files   cifs guest,x-systemd.automount,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.11  0   0

Logged into the machine that's mounting the share, I look at the attributes of a file:
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
--S-----cE-I----xFNP-- /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
s---i---c-jI-T-CxF---m /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/pw-lite.key 
-u----dAc-j----C--NPV- /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt  
suSD----cEj---------V- /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt  
s-S--a-AcE------xF-PV- /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt  
su-Dia-AcE-I-T---F-P-m /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 

..and so on.
When I log into the machine that's sharing the filesystem, the attributes do not change:
~$ lsattr /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt 
--------------e------- /mnt/nas/files/filename.txt

